# UITableViewのdidSelectRowAtの設定をしたい

Tags: swift

UITableViewのdidSelectRowAtを設定したいと思っています。

以下の3つのファイルを主に使っているのですが、CustomCell.swiftで実装したいのですが、実装方法がわかりません。
ソースコードは全て[GitHub](https://github.com/zunda-pixel/AnkoMovie)に公開しています。

- SearchViewController.swift
  https://github.com/zunda-pixel/AnkoMovie/blob/master/AnkoMovie/SearchViewController.swift
- CustomCell.swift
  https://github.com/zunda-pixel/AnkoMovie/blob/master/AnkoMovie/CustomCell.swift
- DataSource.swift
  https://github.com/zunda-pixel/AnkoMovie/blob/master/AnkoMovie/DataSource.swift

SearchViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController {

    private var tableView = UITableView()
    private var searchBar = UISearchBar()
    private var dataSource = DataSource()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
        //Cellのデータを決定
        tableView.dataSource = dataSource as UITableViewDataSource
        //Cellの登録
        tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }
}
```

Comment: 「CustomCell.swiftで実装したい」というのは、`CustomCell`クラスに、メソッド`tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`を定義したいという意味でしょうか？もしそうなら、できない相談です。別の設計をご検討ください。

Comment: ご質問内容の根幹に関わる部分のソースコードはご質問中にテキストとして記載してくださるようにお願いします。問題点がその外側にある場合など、ソース全体が見られるのは助かりますが、リンク先の内容が変化したり、リンク切れになってしまった場合など、後からこの質問を見た人にとって質問が意味をなさないものになってしまうことになります。「CustomCell.swiftで実装したい」については、nagonsoftware さんの書かれた通りで、もし無理やりやればなんとかなるとしても、MVCモデルの基本を大きく踏み外したことをお手伝いしたがる技術者は滅多にいないだろうと思います。

Comment: StackOverflowを最近始めたばかりで作法がわかっていなくてすいません。ではどのようにすればtableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)を実装できるでしょうか？

Comment: このコメント欄での、質問者さんの反応、ならびに過去の質問者さんの質問を読み直してみて、どうも「`UITableView`のDelegateには、`UITableViewDataSource`と`UITableViewDelegate`の2種類に分かれている。メソッド`tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`は、`UITableViewDelegate`に属している」ということを、質問者さんはご存知ないのではないかという疑問を持つに至りました。ここまでは、とうぜんご存知なはずの基礎知識と決めつけて対応してきましたが、そうでないなら、そうでないとご返事ください。そうすれば、話のすれ違いを起こすことなく、適切な回答ができるのではないかと思います。

Comment: そうですね。それがわかっていなかったです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

オブジェクト指向のプログラミングには、独特のデザインパターンがいくつかあります。デザインパターンを直訳すると、設計様式とでもなるでしょうか。デザインパターンの有名なもののひとつに**MVCデザインパターン**があります。（[ウィキペディア「Model View Controller」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller)）
macOS、iOS等のインターフェイスのフレームワーク（iOSでは、UIKit）は、このMVCデザインパターンに準拠して構成されています。なので、`Controller`が名前に含まれるクラスが多数あります。特に`UITableView`は、MVCデザインパターンの考え方を、強く反映したクラスとなっています。
ひとつ、質問者さんにこちらから質問してみましょう。100行あるTableViewがあるとします。この`UITableView`インスタンスは、いくつの`UITableViewCell`インスタンスを持っているでしょうか？「100個」ではありません。画面上に10行表示されていたとすると、スクロールを考慮してもせいぜい12個の`UITableViewCell`のインスタンスを持っているだけです。データの数と、データを表示するセルの数は一致しません。Model（データ）とView（表示）を分離するという、MVCデザインパターンの基本的な考え方を、反映している結果です。
`UITableView`のDelegateは2種類あります。`UITableViewDataSource`と`UITableViewDelegate`です。ふたつに分かれているのは、まさしくMVCデザインパターンに準拠しているからです。`UITableViewDataSource`は、Model（データ）を管理しているオブジェクト（クラス）へ委譲し、`UITableViewDelegate`は、Viewを制御しているオブジェクト（クラス）へ委譲します。

[Protocol UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource)
[Protocol UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate)

メソッド`tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`が、`UITableViewDelegate`のメソッドであることを確認してください。
委譲先が「Viewを制御しているオブジェクト」ならば、ここでは、`SearchViewController`にするのが妥当ですが、もちろんMVCデザインパターンの準拠が絶対ということではありません。テーブルのセルをタップして、選択状態にしたら、どういう挙動をするのかを考えて、委譲先を決定するのがいいでしょう。
移譲先`UITableViewDataSource`を、`tableView.dataSource = dataSource as UITableViewDataSource`と指定したように、移譲先`UITableViewDelegate`も、`tableView.delegate = self`と指定します。

---

以下は、質問から離れて、ご提示のコードを見て、「それはちょっとまずいでしょ？」と感じたところをお話しします。
まず、以下のサンプルコードを実際に動かしてみてください。XcodeのPlaygroundで動くように書いてあります。

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class DataSource: NSObject {
    
    let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
    
    var fruitsArray: [String]
    
    /* シングルトンの定型的な書き方。*/
    static let shared = DataSource()
    
    private override init() {
        fruitsArray = ["Apple", "Banana", "Candy", "Donut"]
    }
    /* ここまで */
}

extension DataSource: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fruitsArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = fruitsArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var tableView: UITableView
    
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .plain)
        
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        /* Storyboardでなく、コードを使ってViewをAuto Layoutでレイアウトする時の書き方*/
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        /* ここまで */
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: DataSource.shared.reuseIdentifier)
        tableView.dataSource = DataSource.shared
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected")
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

`UITableView`のDelegate`UITableViewDataSource`の委譲先のインスタンスには、ふたつの条件があります。ひとつは、オブジェクトTable Viewが存在している間、移譲先のオブジェクトも存在していなければならないという点。もうひとつは、ただひとつだけ存在するインスタンスでなければならないという点です。これらの条件を満たすには、オブジェクト指向のもうひとつのデザインパターンである、[シングルトン（Singleton）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_%E3%83%91%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3)を採用するのがいいでしょう。

View（もちろんTable Viewも含みます）の画面上のレイアウトには、Auto Layoutを使ってください。使用しないと、iPhone/iPadを横向きにするだけで、レイアウトが破綻してしまうことに、早く気づいてください。